# как правильно создать запрос с двумя select -ми?

Tags: php, mysql, select

Задача: есть 500 заемщиков, некоторые из них имеют по несколько кредитов.
В таблице **mysql** имеются данные 1116 кредитов этих 500 заемщиков.
В столбце g_id имеются значения: от 1 до 500, например если у значение №1 имеется 4 кредита, то среди 1116 записей значение №1 будет 4 раза.

**1-select**: с условием просрочек, выборка показала 111  (91 с distict-ом),
т.е. 91 заемщиков из 500 - в группе плохих.

**2-select**: where not условия 1-ого select-а, выборка показала 468 с dist.,

Теперь необходимо сделать выборку на основе 2-ого select-а, которая сможет показать те уникальные значения из того же столбца, в которых нет этих 91 значения (из 1-ого select-а).
в результате: выборка должна показать 500-91 = 409 значений хорошего кредита.

Пытался так: `("select g_id form(select-2) where not (select-1)")`.
не получается.

1-й select:

```
$a=$bank->query("SELECT distinct G_id FROM `prosroc` WHERE  
(((amount<=1001 and currency='USD') or (amount<=8500 and currency='TJS') and credit_term<=12) and num_overdue>10)

or
((((amount<=1001 and currency='USD') or (amount<=8500 and currency='TJS')) and (credit_term between 13 and 24)) and num_overdue>15)

or
((((amount<=1001 and currency='USD') or (amount<=8500 and currency='TJS')) and credit_term between 25 and 36) and num_overdue>18)

or
((((amount between 1001 and 3001) and currency='USD') or ((amount between 8500 and 24000) and currency='TJS')) and credit_term<=12
and num_overdue>10)
or
(((((amount between 1001 and 3001) and currency='USD') or ((amount between 8500 and 24000) and currency='TJS'))
 and (credit_term between 13 and 24)) and num_overdue>15)

 or
(((((amount between 1001 and 3001) and currency='USD') or ((amount between 8500 and 24000) and currency='TJS'))
 and (credit_term between 25 and 36)) and num_overdue>18)

 or
 ((((amount>3001 and currency='USD') or (amount>24000 and currency='TJS')) and (credit_term<=12)) and num_overdue>10)
 or
 ((((amount>3001 and currency='USD') or (amount>24000 and currency='TJS')) and (credit_term between 13 and 24)) 
and num_overdue>15)

or
((((amount>3001 and currency='USD') or (amount>24000 and currency='TJS')) and (credit_term between 25 and 36)) 
and num_overdue>18)");


$a_2=$a->num_rows;
echo "Количество плохих кредитов : ".$a_2.";
```

Comment: а сами `select ...` можно посмотреть?

Comment: код вправил в текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдет NOT IN:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM    table_1
  WHERE   id NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  id
    FROM    table1 t1
    )
```

Comment: то, что нужно, благодарю за помощь)

Comment: @Амирхон Примите ответ как правильный.